# How to pass multiple values to server using <input> tag and access using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongoose

I working on a simple blog website for which i want an input tag to send two data to backend. This include the title of blogpost and the Id of blogpost. I have used mongoose to set up the database. How do I pass multiple values using input tag.

I have tried using

```
<input type="hidden" name="button" value="*any-value*" data-value="*other-value*"></input>
```

but how do I access these data in backend using node.js. I have also tried this using an a tag

```
<a href="#" name="a-button" data-value="*some-value*">Subimt</a>
```

But this is not working. Please help.

Comment: Are you using Express with your node server?

Comment: Use two input tags?

Answer (score 0):

Create a form element that calls a JavaScript function to submit, something like this:

```
<form id="form" action="javascript:void(0)">
    <input id="data" type="hidden" name="button" value="*any-value*" data-value="*other-value*" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then define the function in a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        var data = document.getElementById('data');
        var value = data.value;
        var dataValue = data.getAttribute('data-value');
        fetch('/api/blog', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                value,
                dataValue
            })
        });
    }
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', submit);
</script>
```

Then parse the data on your server to handle this, with (if you are using Express):

```
app.get('/api/blog', (req, res) => {
    const { value, dataValue } = req.body;
    console.log(value, dataValue);
});
```